# On Ubuntu - /var/log/messages timestamps are 4 minutes ahead

Tags: logs, timestamps, time

As mentioned in the subject, timestamps in my /var/log/messages are 4 minutes ahead comparing to my desktop clock or the `date` command. If it was an hour, I would think this is a timezone issue, but four minutes?

Here's an example, at 09:09 I hibernated and then awakened my computer and the log looks like this:

```
Feb 16 **09:13:01** konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20141107/psargs-359) 
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\x5c_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff8802170d39d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20141107/psparse-536)
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20141107/psargs-359) 
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\x5c_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF] (Node ffff8802170d39d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20141107/psparse-536)
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

Not that I'm worried, but I'm interested why this happens.

Additionally, here is a piece of var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 16 09:13:01 konrad-ACT-MT kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133

(...)

2016-02-16 Feb 16 09:09:18 konrad-ACT-MT anacron[8855]: Normal exit (0

Normal exit (0 jobs run) Feb 16 09:10:07 konrad-ACT-MT CRON[9006]:

(root) CMD (/bin/date > /var/log/xbackup)
```

So it starts on 09:13, then we have 09:09 and then  09:10. This doesn't sound like a sequence. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you have `ntp` and `ntpdate` installed?

Comment: @FaheemMitha ntp: no, ntpdate - yes.  But please note, that the "date" command shows the correct date & time.

Comment: Quite odd. Is your BIOS date ok?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes, BIOS date & time are OK